# Ethereum contract do not change it state while minting

Tags: ethereum, abi, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

There is sol contract function mint():

```
 function mint(address _holder, uint _value) external {
require(msg.sender == ico);
require(_value != 0);
require(totalSupply + _value <= TOKEN_LIMIT);

balances[_holder] += _value;
totalSupply += _value;
Transfer(0x0, _holder, _value);  }
```

I'm succkessfully calling this function for creating 10000 tokens and send them to eth.accounts[0]:

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
>
> true
>
> minedContract.mint.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[0], 10000, {from:eth.accounts[0]})
>
> "0x6e4474072ebf2836fa6b737a6341504f79b53417e366c742c7ffefa0f3aff832"

But balance of eth.accounts[0] still 0. Total balance of the contract is 0 either. I have waited till its mined.
Why state of the contract isn't changing?

Comment: How are you checking the balance?

Comment: minedContract.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0])

Comment: Could you share the code for `balanceOf`? Also, is the transaction actually successful? (Maybe it's being reverted... e.g. perhaps `msg.sender != ico`.)

Comment: Just BaseToken method: function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

Comment: Transaction was successful.

Comment: Sorry. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the transaction was successful? Can you share the transaction receipt?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YqrGXT8n

Comment: That's not the transaction receipt. The transaction receipt is available after the transaction has been mined. You can use `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash)` to retrieve it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yuseWfps

Comment: Hmm, the receipt seems to be missing the `status` field, which was going to be how we could confirm that the transaction succeeded. What node are you talking to? Is this a local test network? If so, what software? You said the transaction succeeded... how do you know?

Comment: Only as far as i know. I'm newbie at this topic. Yes, this is geth local subchain.

Comment: My assumption then would be that the transaction is failing. Try removing the `require` statements. Assuming things work then, add them back in one at a time to find out which one is the culprit. (My guess is still that `msg.sender != ico`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have repeated my own steps to reproduce above behavior but failed because everything works well. So closed because of a human factor.